# String Array to String conversion Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, alamofire

I have a string array stored in nsuserdefaults under `someKey` key.

I'm building the `Alamofire` query:

```
var params = [
        "long": lon,
        "lat": lat,
        "startDate": DateCalc.convertValueToDate(defaults.floatForKey("startDate"))
    ] as [String: AnyObject]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(serverURL)/tests", parameters: (params))
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
```

Now, based on some conditions, I would like to append to my `params` array the previously set String array.

I tried doing it like this:

```
params["someKey"] = defaults.objectForKey("someKey")
```

but then the input params look as follows:

```
params: ["long": 19.09421499999999, "someKey": <__NSCFArray 0x7f8322713990>(
```

one,
two,
three
)
, "lat": 51.90671500000001,"startDate": 2011-09-28T00:00:00.000Z]

how should I change it so that I can pass the array of strings instead, e.g.:

```
params: ["long": 19.09421499999999, "someKey": "one, two three", "lat": 51.90671500000001,"startDate": 2011-09-28T00:00:00.000Z]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let joinedString = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"].joinWithSeparator(", ")

print(joinedString)
```

Comment: can you suggest me a `swift` version of that? I tried `.characters.split(" ").map { String($0) }` but it didn't work due to error that `value of type AnyObject? has no type characters`

Comment: please check it now

Comment: I have suggested an edit to this question for better visibility and help to others. Please accept that.

Comment: hm, btw, one more question - is it hard to make from it the array such as `["one","two","three"]` ? I tried to write `var stringArray: [String] = defaults.arrayForKey("someKey") as! [String]
params["someKey"] = [stringArray.joinWithSeparator(", ")]` but the result is wrong again: `<_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray...`. When I wrote it without `[ ]` I got a string, not an array of single words. Can you suggest me a solution for that?

Comment: Just make string prefixed with [ and suffixed with ] -- :-) , when you simply write [...] you get an array, which is why your answer is getting incorrect.